# Insert input to exe program with linux script

Tags: linux, bash

I got a script that asks 1000 times for input of 1-5, it looks like this:

insert1:

insert2:

insert3:

insert4:

insert5:
//and again 1-5

insert 1:
...in total it will get 1000 inputs

I want to write a one line script that will run the script I just described, it will insert the input that needed each time.
this is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
./my_script.exe  -l | for i in {1..200}; do for j in {1..5}; do j; done; done
```

Comment: Remember, a pipe connects the _output_ of the thing on the left to the _input_ of the thing on the right. (And `j` just runs the command `j`, it doesn't have anything to do with the contents of the variable expanded with `$j`).

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there, but do it the other way around:

```
for i in {1..200} ; do
    for j in {1..5} ; do
        echo $j
    done
done | ./myscript.exe -l
```

You can put a `#` before the `|` to comment it out and see what the script sends to your program.

---

You need to differentiate between parameters which are specified after the program name like this:

```
program param1 param2 param3
```

and inputs, which a program gets by reading its `stdin` and are supplied like this:

```
printf "input1\ninput2\ninput3\n" | program
```

Alternative version of second command:

```
{ echo input1; echo input2; echo input3; } | program
```

Comment: @Rojo There's nothing _wrong_ with your edit _per se;_ but there also was nothing wrong with the original code. If you have a reason for changing the `for` loops, can you please share it?